# How to handle OAuth2 and custom JWT authentication?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

Currently my Spring Boot app authenticates users using JWT which it also generates:

**Security config:**

```java
public SecurityFilterChain customFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
               .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
               .authorizeRequests(auth -> auth
                   .anyRequest().authenticated()
               )
               .userDetailsService(userService)
               .addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), userService))
               .addFilterBefore(new AuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
               .build();
}
```

**AuthorizationFilter:**

```java
public class AuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        if (!hasAuthorizationToken(request)) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
        try {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = JwtTokenUtil.decodeJwtToken(authorizationHeader);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Authorization error: " + ex.getMessage());
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Now I would like to add OAuth2 auth in addition to existing one. I have added `oauth2ResourceServer` to the config:

```java
public SecurityFilterChain customFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
               .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
               .authorizeRequests(auth -> auth
                   .anyRequest().authenticated()
               )
               .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth -> {
                    oauth
                         .jwt()
                              .jwtAuthenticationConverter(oAuthJwtAuthenticationConverter);
               })
               .userDetailsService(userService)
               .addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), userService))
               .addFilterBefore(new AuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
               .build();
}
```

Now when sending a request with OAuth2, it works well, but when sending my custom JWT I get an error

> An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Signed JWT rejected: Another algorithm expected, or no matching key(s) found

How can I handle two types of JWT?

Comment: How should Spring Security know, which JWT the request contains? It tries it and fails, because the JWT is the wrong one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that by splitting the config into two separate `SecurityFilterChain` classes and implementing `RequestMatcher` for each of those:

```
public SecurityFilterChain fooFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  return http
    .requestMatcher(new FooMatcher())
    // rest of the config
    .build();
}


public SecurityFilterChain barFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  return http
    .requestMatcher(new BarMatcher())
    // rest of the config
    .build();
}
```

RequestMatcher:

```
public class FooMatcher implements RequestMatcher {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return <some condition for Foo config>
    }
}
```